# Where does the 'Status' field belong?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have two tables, let's call them `leave_request` and the other one `leave_given`.

The employee submit a `leave_request` to take a vacation where he has to fill place of vacation, date of start, date of end, reason etc.

The boss of that employee will proceed that request and decide whether the employee can take the vacation or not. If he gives him one, `leave_given` is filled with the details that the employee gave (date start and date end might change as the boss may not like the dates).

Now, regarding the 'Status' of the request. I was first thinking that If `id` of `leave_request` is not found on `leave_given` then It's **rejected** If it's there then It's **accepted** which I believe make sense.

I'm however writing an application and I want the user to know If the request has not been proceed yet so I will have to add a `status` field.

My question is, does it make sense to do the following:

- Add `status` in `leave_request`?
- Once the employee make a request, Status is **on hold** by default.
- If the boss accepts it, `status` will change to **Accepted** and It will be added to `leave_given`. If rejected, the status will change to Rejected and nothing will be added to `leave_given`.

Comment: I would use a single table (e.g. leave) with status values requested, accepted, and rejected.

Comment: I have to make two because the requested may not be the same as the given one. Can we say that my proposition make sense If we are using two tables?

Comment: With the single table design, there would be separate columns instead of tables. The request dates would be NOT NULL and accepted dates NULL until the request is accepted.

Comment: @black, is there any possibility of a manager giving leave without a request.  To answer your question specifically, a status on leave request will be required under any scenario to record denied requests

Comment: @LJ01 Yes, that would be possible.

Comment: @black. On that basis I would suggest that there are two different events, leave request and leave granted. A leave granted has an optional'source request' and a leave request has a status. granting leave creates a leave granted entry. Say 3 days were requested and day 1 + day 3 we're granted (not day 2) you could end up with 2 leave granted / request, and then leave taken should theoretically be a separate entity too, in order to be able to handle where an employee takes more / less leave than Is granted...